# Lookup IP using while loop issue using ipaddress library

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframes.

- "DF1" is traffic from logs with hour, time, and destination address containing approx. 2 million rows.
- "DF2" is ASN information where I took the start and end address and converted it to CIDR notation with approx. 800,000 rows.

I am trying to lookup the address from "DF1" in the CIDR field in "DF2", then add the ASN number associated with the CIDR block to "DF1". Since I have such large data sets I was curious of the best was to accomplish this?

```
DF1
    address 
0   8.47.124.1  
1   63.215.97.2 
2   8.47.124.2  
3   63.215.97.1 
4   8.47.124.1
5   8.47.124.2  
6   8.47.124.1  
7   8.47.124.1  

DF2
   ASN   CIDR
0   1    [IPNetwork('8.47.124.0/29')]
1   1    [IPNetwork('8.45.244.0/29')]
2   2    [IPNetwork('63.215.97.8/29')]
3   1    [IPNetwork('8.13.232.64/27')]
4   2    [IPNetwork('63.215.97.16/29')]
5   2    [IPNetwork('63.215.97.24/29')]
6   1    [IPNetwork('8.13.228.128/27')]
7   1    [IPNetwork('8.13.228.96/27')]
```

Desired output:

```
DF1
   address         asn
0   8.47.124.1     1
1   63.215.97.2    2
2   8.47.124.2     1
3   63.215.97.1    2
4   8.47.124.1     1
5   8.47.124.2     1
6   8.47.124.1     1
7   8.47.124.1     1
```

I am getting closer:

```
import ipaddress

#Create new column "ASN" to DF1
DF1["ASN"] = ""

#While loop uses the library ipaddress that checks if address from "DF1" is in CIDR block of "DF2"
index = 0  
while(index < lenth):
  DF1["sourceaddress"].iloc[index] in DF2["CIDR"].iloc[index]

  DF1["ASN"].iloc[index] = DF2["ASN"].iloc[index]
  index = index + 1
```

But this is only giving me 1 all the way down for the ASN. I think it is just giving me the ASN of the position in DF2 instead of the ASN when the IP from DF1 matches the CIDR in DF2.

Comment: You are correct, let me fix this. @ScottBoston

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider building substrings of the IP addresses from first number to last period then merge together:

```
DF1['IP_Sub'] = DF1['address'].apply(lambda x: x[0:x.rindex('.')])

DF2['IP_Sub'] = DF2['CIDR'].apply(lambda x: x[12:x.rindex('.')])
DF2 = DF2[['IP_Sub', 'ASN']].drop_duplicates()

# MERGE DFs
DF3 = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, on='IP_Sub')[['address', 'ASN']]

print(DF3)
#        address  ASN
# 0   8.47.124.1    1
# 1   8.47.124.2    1
# 2   8.47.124.1    1
# 3   8.47.124.2    1
# 4   8.47.124.1    1
# 5   8.47.124.1    1
# 6  63.215.97.2    2
# 7  63.215.97.1    2

# MERGE DFs (MAINTAIN ORIGINAL INDEX)
DF3 = (DF1.reset_index()
          .merge(DF2, on='IP_Sub', sort=False)
          .filter(['index', 'address', 'ASN'])
          .set_index('index').sort_index()
          .rename_axis(None))
print(DF3)
#        address  ASN
# 0   8.47.124.1    1
# 1  63.215.97.2    2
# 2   8.47.124.2    1
# 3  63.215.97.1    2
# 4   8.47.124.1    1
# 5   8.47.124.2    1
# 6   8.47.124.1    1
# 7   8.47.124.1    1
```

Comment: I knew I was approaching this all wrong.  Worked like a charm!  Thank you! @Parfait

Comment: Excellent! Seeing `Series` processes over loops is a learning process!